# Validar campos con Javascript setCustomValidity

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Hola buenas tardes estoy intentando validar unos campos con setCustomValidity, las validaciones consisten en que si un input fecha esta vacío y el otro no o viceversa pintar los campos en color rojo y poner texto les anexo una imagen como ejemplo de lo que intento hacer. La validación ya la tengo, pero no logro pintar y mostrar el mensaje. Les comparto el formulario y código.

> Resultado esperado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Formulario

```js
$("#nc").click(function(){  
  var date_inicio = $("#date-inicio").find("input").val();
  var date_fin = $("#date-fin").find("input").val(); 

  if (date_inicio.length == 0 && date_fin.length == 0 || date_inicio.length > 0 && date_fin.length > 0) {
    getAllTicketsAjax();
  } else {
    alert("bien");

    date_inicio.setCustomValidity('The email address entered is already registerd.');
  }  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="col-12 form" id="registration">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Fecha Inicio:</label>
          <div class="input-group date" id="date-inicio" data-target-input="nearest">
              <input id="date-inicio" name="date-inicio" type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#date-inicio"/>
              <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#date-inicio" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                  <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <p id="p-date-inicio"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
      <!-- /.form group -->
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Fecha Fin:</label>
          <div class="input-group date" id="date-fin" data-target-input="nearest">
              <input id="date-fin" name="date-fin" type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#date-fin"/>
              <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#date-fin" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                  <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <p id="p-date-fin"></p>
      </div>
      <!-- /.form group -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 align-self-center" style="padding-top: 1.5%">
        <button type="button" id="nc" class="btn btn-block bg-gradient-info"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

> Error

***TypeError: date_inicio.setCustomValidity is not a function***

En el else es donde intento pintar el input y mostrar el mensaje de error.

Espero que me puedan, apoyar por favor.

Comment: Estás creando variable sobre el valor del campo `var date_inicio = $("#date-inicio").find("input").val();` y debería ser sobre el campo `var date_inicio = $("#date-inicio").find("input");`

Comment: Ya le hice como mencionas y me sigue mostrando el mismo error

Answer (score 0):

Estás obteniendo el valor del campo `var date_inicio = $("#date-inicio").find("input").val();` y no puedes usar esta variable para asignar la validación.

Luego, la API de jQuery no incluye el método `setCustomValidity`, que pertenece al DOM. Puedes obtener el elemento del DOM (input) con las funciones nativas de Javascript o agregando `[0]` al final de la selección hecha con jQuery ([Método .get()](https://api.jquery.com/get/)):

```js
$("#nc").click(function(){  
  var date_inicio = $("#date-inicio").find("input").val();
  var date_fin = $("#date-fin").find("input").val(); 

  if (date_inicio.length == 0 && date_fin.length == 0 || date_inicio.length > 0 && date_fin.length > 0) {
    getAllTicketsAjax();
  } else {
    alert("bien");
    // No puedes usar la variable date_inicio,
    // Porque contiene el valor, no el elemento del DOM (input)
    // Agrega [0] al final de la selección de jQuery
    $("#date-inicio").find("input")[0].setCustomValidity('The email address entered is already registerd.');
  }  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="col-12 form" id="registration">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Fecha Inicio:</label>
          <div class="input-group date" id="date-inicio" data-target-input="nearest">
              <input id="date-inicio" name="date-inicio" type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#date-inicio"/>
              <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#date-inicio" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                  <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <p id="p-date-inicio"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
      <!-- /.form group -->
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Fecha Fin:</label>
          <div class="input-group date" id="date-fin" data-target-input="nearest">
              <input id="date-fin" name="date-fin" type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#date-fin"/>
              <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#date-fin" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                  <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <p id="p-date-fin"></p>
      </div>
      <!-- /.form group -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 align-self-center" style="padding-top: 1.5%">
        <button type="button" id="nc" class="btn btn-block bg-gradient-info"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Nota:** Estás duplicando ID para div e input; recuerda que los IDs deben ser únicos para evitar cualquier problema de acceso y manipulación de elementos.

Comment: me manda el siguiente error $(...).find(...)[0] is undefined

Comment: Qué raro, en el snippet funciona bien y copié tu código, modificando solo la última línea. El error es porque no está encontrando el elemento, ya sea el que buscas con `$(...)` o con `.find(...)`